Trino + Apache Phoenix: Unable to query Phoenix from Trino container, yet URL is reachable
I am running HBase 2.5.8 with Phoenix 5.2.0 on a WSL2 machine
I am able to interact with Phoenix through sqlline.py:
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select * from US_POPULATION;
+-------+--------------+------------+
| STATE |     CITY     | POPULATION |
+-------+--------------+------------+
| AZ    | Phoenix      | 1461575    |
...
+-------+--------------+------------+
10 rows selected (0.027 seconds)

I have phoenix.properties mounted into my Trino v451 container:
connector.name=phoenix5
phoenix.connection-url=jdbc:phoenix:172.27.66.133:2181:/hbase

From a shell inside of Trino, I am able to verify that 172.27.66.133:2181 is reachable:
ssh-5.1$ curl -I 172.27.66.133:2181
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

user@system:~/downloads/hbase-2.5.8/bin$ lsof -i tcp | grep 2181
java     82019 user  289u  IPv6 2774256      0t0  TCP *:2181 (LISTEN)
java     82019 user  394u  IPv6 2768210      0t0  TCP localhost:59930->localhost:2181 (ESTABLISHED)
java     82019 user  395u  IPv6 2774267      0t0  TCP localhost:2181->localhost:59930 (ESTABLISHED)
java     82019 user  500u  IPv6 2758933      0t0  TCP localhost:59942->localhost:2181 (ESTABLISHED)
java     82019 user  501u  IPv6 2774271      0t0  TCP localhost:2181->localhost:59942 (ESTABLISHED)
java     82019 user  513u  IPv6 2927407      0t0  TCP 172.27.66.133:2181->system:54154 (ESTABLISHED)

However, trying to run something like show schemas in phoenix hangs forever
trino> show schemas in phoenix;

Query 20240711_172128_00000_uwvpk, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 11 total, 0 done (0.00%)
5:17 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query aborted by user

I'm really confused as to what could be going on.
